# Enterprise Library Logging - Send email with line-breaks

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I use Enterprise Library Logging to log errors and to send some notifications. 
I've configured Email Listener.
I need to send some list of warnings at the end of user session.

```
Log.LogMessage(String.Join(vbCrLf, Errors), Log.Severity.Error, LOG_CATEGORY)
```

But in email I've no line-breaks separated messages.
I've got something like this:

> error1 error2 error3

Is it possible to send line-breaking message in Enterprise Library Logging?

Comment: When i use "vbLf & vbCr" i have double line-break. In other case i've no line-breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use Environment.NewLine instead of vbCrLf and see what happens?

```
Log.LogMessage(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Errors), Log.Severity.Error, LOG_CATEGORY)
```

Test it out with:

```
DIM Errors As String() = {"Errors","Errors2","Errors3"}
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Errors)
```